# Inline-Block with 2 or more elements besides

Tags: html, css

I try to work out, that the two `p` should be besides the image and the second `p` not under the image. It would be possible with `float: left` but this causes a lot of browser bugs (mainly under IE). How could I get my wished result with `display: inline-block`?

```
<div id="one">
    <img src="http://www.jcopro.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ubuntu-logo1.gif" alt="" />
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

---

```
#one {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 800px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#one img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}

#one p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MK5E9/1/

Edit:
Okay I mis-described my problem: I don't want to have the `p` in one row besides each other, I want to have them under each and both paragraphs besides the image.

Comment: Your wrapper (#one) isn't wide enough to hold your elements. Each `<p>` is 600px wide. Either increase the width of the wrapper or shrink the width of the `<p>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Yes, but you need the container to be wide enough to contain all 3 elements. The following works when shrinking you `<p>`s to 300px wide.</s>

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MK5E9/2/)**

EDIT, based one OP's edit:

Well, that's what float was actually originally meant for. Floating images and allowing the correct flow of text around them. **[Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2878011)**.

If you wish for the image to be on a different "column", meaning the text won't flow around the image, but will start a new line at the line of the image, you need to limit the width of your elements. **[See here.](http://dabblet.com/gist/2878013)**

Comment: Sorry for my dis-description, this isn't that what I need. See edit for more info.